# I want to create a thread based on user value in perl

Tags: perl

please help me on this.

I want to create thread based on user request.

Example: if user give the value 7. then i want to create 7 threads

Please answer in perl

Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: how would you go about creating 7 threads if it wasn't from user input and you always wanted 7?  what are these threads *doing*?

Comment: What problem did you encounter when you tried to code this?

Answer (score 1):

The process of creating threads is very simple.

This will do what you ask. It starts the specified number of threads and then calls `join` on all of them to wait until they complete.

No doubt the `process` subroutine will need to be something a little more elaborate!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

print 'Enter number of threads: ';
chomp(my $n = <STDIN>);

my @threads;
for (1 .. $n){
  push @threads, threads->create(\&process, $_);
}

$_->join for @threads;

sub process {
  my ($n) = @_;
  sleep 1 + rand 5;
  print "Ending thread $n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/Perl

use strict;
use threads;


my $num_of_threads = <STDIN>;


my @threads = init(); #initialize threads

# Loop through all threads
foreach(@threads){
                # doWork is subroutine you want each thread to perform
        $_ = threads->create(\&doWork);
}

# Join all threads
foreach(@threads){
    $_->join();
}


sub init{
    my @Threads;
    for(my $i = 1;$i<=$num_of_threads;$i++){
        push(@Threads,$i);
    }
    return @Threads;
}
```